# EditText validation not working

Tags: android, regex

I'm having trouble with validation input from EditText.
Whenever I click on SaveData button, the dialop popup no matter what it is valid or not.
Here is the sample what I wrote:

Validation class:

```
package android.week04Lab03;

import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import android.webkit.URLUtil;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class Validation {

public boolean isEmpty(EditText txt){

    if(txt.getText().toString().equals("")){            
        return false;
    } else
        return true;

}

public boolean isURL (EditText txt){
    if (!URLUtil.isValidUrl(txt.getText().toString())){
        return false;
    } 
    return true;
}

public boolean isEmail (EditText txt){
    String isEmail = "^([^@\\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\\.)+[a-z]{2,})$";
    Pattern isEmailPattern = Pattern.compile(isEmail);
    Matcher mailMatcher = isEmailPattern.matcher(txt.getText().toString());
    if (!mailMatcher.find()) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

}
```

Here is the activity class

```
public class MetaData extends Activity {
Validation validator;
ImageView angel;
EditText name, loc, keyword, date, mail;
ToggleButton share;
RatingBar rating;
Button save;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_meta_data);        
    name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
    ..........................

public void saveData(View v) {
    Validation validator = new Validation();

    if (!validator.isEmpty(name)) {

        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alert.setTitle("Input Validation Warning");
        alert.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        alert.setMessage("Error found, please enter your information correctly!");
        alert.setPositiveButton("OK",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        return;

                    }
                });
        alert.show();
    }

}
```

Comment: instead of using `if(txt.getText().toString() == "")` to compare the string, maybe using `if(txt.getText().toString().equals(""))` instead?

Comment: @ss1271, Please format your response as an answer.

Comment: use txt.getText().toString().equals("") in isEmpty method. == is for numerical operations.

Comment: I also did that, but the fact is It seems that `isEmpty()` method doesn't return values. I don't know what's wrong here

Comment: note that `String.isEmpty()` is not available as a method on some older Android devices, I had to replace it with a check for `length() == 0` for my App to work on some old HTC devices

Comment: Tks guys, I sorted it out :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `if(txt.getText().toString() == "")` to compare the string, could you try using `if(txt.getText().toString().equals(""))` instead?

---

Apart from your question, I found there might be a little bit mess in your logic:

First, you did this String comparison

```
public boolean isEmpty(EditText txt){

    if(txt.getText().toString() == ""){         
        return false;
    } else
        return true;

}
```

Which you were trying to do, is to `return false` on your `isEmpty` method if the string in the EditText is empty, or `return true` otherwise.

Then, you did this `if (!validator.isEmpty(name))` in your `saveDate()` method, which means, according to your code:

```
if (validator.isEmpty(name) == false) // isEmpty returned false, means getText got an empty String
```

Why not make `isEmpty` to `return true` if the EditText is empty? That'll make you easier to understand the code later.

Comment: +1 for first answer...Actually you deserve rep for this question

Answer (score 2):

That is not the way to check whether string is empty or not. Because it will fail if you have one or more spaces in your Edittext.

So check length like this

```
 if(txt.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0){         
        return false;
    } else
        return true;
```

And also you should compare strings with the `equals` method.

When you give something in between "" to compare, == will also be treated as equals. So no problem in that case.

Answer (score 2):

Just use equals() instead of == for check string is empty or not

`txt.getText().toString().equals("")` instead of `txt.getText().toString() == ""`

**==** compare two object not its value

Answer (score 0):

```
      EditText e1;
e1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et1); 
int et1=e1.getText().toString().trim().length();

        public boolean isEmpty(EditText txt){

           if(et1>0)
        {            
                return false;
            } else
                return true;

        }
    try This..May Be Its Helpfull For You.
```